# Python code to split a combined .CIF file into separate files

Tags: python, bash

I need help writing a python code that takes a combined .CIF file and for each data block it should split it into a separate file corresponding to the order or index 1,2,3... (For example: 1.cif, 2.cif, and so on).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this relate to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_Information_File ?